# How can I customize the Windows Explorer sidebar?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I want to be able to customize the sidebar like a Mac. For example, I want to remove the libraries.
I am using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a library by right-clicking on one of them and clicking "Delete". If you want to keep one of them, click on "Don't show in navigation pane". To remove favorites, right-click and click "Remove". Removing mounted drives in the sidebar is not possible, removing headers is not possible either. (Maybe it is possible by changing registry values, but I don't know about that.)

Comment: Can´t put the library back now after ticking that box.

Answer (score 1):

[How to Disable Libraries in Windows 7](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-libraries-feature-in-windows-7/)

[How to Remove Libraries in Windows 7](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-libraries-from-windows-7-explorers-navigation-pane/)

[How to Remove Favorites from Explorer Navigation Pane](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-favorites-from-windows-7-explorers-navigation-pane/)

[Source of Information](http://www.askvg.com/search-result/?cx=partner-pub-7540522897650882:810j74-hl9t&cof=FORID:10&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=remove%20explorer%20navigation%20pane&sa=Search&siteurl=www.askvg.com/category/windows-seven/)