# Remove Libraries from Windows 8 Explorer sidebar

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I had removed the Libraries from my Windows 7 with [this registry tweaks](https://superuser.com/questions/301776/how-can-i-customize-the-windows-explorer-sidebar), but since the update to Windows 8 the Libraries are back in my Windows Explorer. 
So I tried to tweak the registry again, but it fails to get permission to change the value (in Windows 7 it worked).

http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-libraries-from-windows-7-explorers-navigation-pane/

Someone know how to remove the Libraries folder or to get the permission to change the value?

Here it fails to get the permission:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried running regedit as admin? (Right click > Run as administrator)

Comment: Yes, same. "Unable to save permission changes on ShellFolder"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the solution in this other [thread about Registry Permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/490944/windows-8-registry-permission-to-change-values):

Launch the `regedit` with WIN+R and go to the following location:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}\ShellFolder
```

Open the "Permission..." on the ShellFolder and open the "Advanced" settings

[image]

Change the Owner to "Administrators"

[image]

Now you can set "Full Control" to the Administrators and change the values.

Now double-click on `Attributes` DWORD and change the value to **b090010d**

And then it is possible to change