# Windows 8 Registry Permission to change values

Tags: windows-registry, windows-8, regex, regedit

Since Windows-8 I'm unable to change values in the registry (different customizations) like [changing the explorer menu](https://superuser.com/questions/485342/remove-libraries-from-windows-8-explorer-sidebar).

Anyone able to **change the value of the key 'Attributes' in the following folder**?

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}\ShellFolder
```

Because I get always the following error message - independent of the key I try to change. This is a general problem and "run as Administrator" on regedit.exe does not work either.
I also tried to change the permission on the folders in the registry, but no success.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have set the **Administrators** group as **Owner** of the key, did you grant **Full Control** to it? Also try granting **Full Control** to **SYSTEM** also.

If that doesn't help, download [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and try the following command, then see if the edits are allowed:

`psexec -i -d -s %windir%\regedit.exe`

Comment: Yes thanks, that's it. Setting the Administrator as Owner (in the Advanced Settings of the Permissions)! This solves also the thread to remove libraries from the Windows Explorer: http://superuser.com/questions/485342/remove-libraries-from-windows-8-explorer-sidebar