# Windows 8.1 Explorer standard libraries can't be removed

Tags: windows-8

After installing Windows 8.1, the 'default' libraries reappeared in Windows Explorer. I removed all of them again but the "Documents" library just keeps coming back, haunting me.

I've deleted it a few times manually now but after each reboot, there is a chance for it to be back.

It's just the "Documents" library, the other standard libraries are not returning (Pictures, ...)

How can I retire the "Documents" Library permanently?

Comment: Same as this question?  http://superuser.com/questions/485342/remove-libraries-from-windows-8-explorer-sidebar?rq=1

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not